# How can I read a text file with size 6GB in Erlang?

Tags: string, file, parsing, erlang

I have 6 GB of text file. I want to read this file and parse the data from each line and save it in my database. But it is not possible to the entire 6 GB file at once due to memory issues. So How can I read the data chunk by chunk and then process it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try the [read](https://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read-2) function. It allows for an argument to limit the number of bytes or characters from the file.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do this now. Let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
process_file(Filename) ->
    {ok, F} = file:open(Filename, [read]),
    process_lines(F).

process_lines(F) ->
    case file:read_line(F) of
        {ok, Line} ->
            %% do something with Line
            process_lines(F);
        eof ->
            file:close(F)
    end.
```

Comment: But even when reading like this, It is crashing due to memory allocation issue. It's not possible to read even the first line.

`eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 105746219880 bytes of memory (of type "heap_frag")`

Comment: This type of code shouldn't run out of memory - garbage collection should be able to reclaim the memory used for lines already read. Most likely some other piece of your code is trying to allocate 105 GB.

Comment: I'm not sure why, But it is creating problem. I am not running any other code on this server and it is a server with pretty decent specs. Anyways, I'm trying to read the file as chunks or small parts. Its working as of now.